# how to set cron job from php script?

Tags: php, cron

i am new to cron job . i studied some basics about cron job . i can able to call php using cron tab. By using following command in /etc/crontab

```
  10 *    * * *   root    /usr/bin/php /var/www/PATH TO SCRIPT/email.php
```

In email.php i have following code

```
 #!/usr/bin/php
 <?php
    mail ("examplemail@mail.com", "Cron Successful Public HTML!","Hello World from mycron.php!");
 ?>
```

For every 10mins i am getting mail. 
But i need to know is there any way to call cron job from php ( invoke cron from php)
i get some idea by surfing but i am not able to figure out the exact way to do my job . 
Here is code which i used to add job by using php

```
   exec('echo -e "crontab -e \n2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/PATH TO THE SCRIPT/crontest1.php" ');
```

Its not working for me. can anyone please guide me how to call or add cron from php. so tat i can send mail by executing php file & can able change time interval in php file itself.

Answer (score 10):

From [How can I set cron job through PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134952/how-can-i-set-cron-job-through-php-script/5135390#5135390) by [Nick Clark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630716/nick-clark):

> This will add a script that runs every day at 9:30am.
>
> ```
> exec('echo -e "`crontab -l`\n30 9 * * * /path/to/script" | crontab -');
> ```
>
> You may run into problems with permissions if you are running this script from a web server. To get around this, I would suggest a different approach.
>
> Here is one possible solution. Create a list of scripts that need to be run. You can save this in a text file or in a database. Create a script to read this list and run it every minute or every 5 minutes (using a cronjob). Your script will need to be smart enough to decide when to run the list of scripts and when to simply exit.

You can do like this..

Other links:

[Install a cron job with a php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037176/install-a-cron-job-with-a-php-script)

[How to invoke cron job from php script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511996/how-to-invoke-cron-job-from-php-script)

Comment: i tried this , i just want to know after this i have to run my php file in browser ? i really don't have any idea how that cron will execute. can please explain it :(

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add it directly

```
echo "2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/PATH TO THE SCRIPT/crontest1.php\n" > /etc/cron.d/username
```

Comment: The OP specifically asked how to do this from PHP.

Comment: @MichaelMior Put an `exec()` around it... When I look at the question, it seems, that he understands it.

Answer (score 0):

Many environments do not permit writing to a text file from a php page called from the web.  I agree that this is a security risk that one should not take.

I have a webpage save data to a MySQL table via a JQuery call to a php script.  In Cron, I schedule another php script to, every so often, check data in MySQL table and execute whatever jobs necessary.