# How to set cron job manually on a shared host

Tags: php, cron

I'm on a shared hosting plan at Bluehost and set up cron jobs through the cpanel cron job tab.  I'm able to specify the periodicity and issue a command to trigger the php script.  Is there a way from PHP to issue a cron job and set the periodicity and also from PHP to remove the cron job?  Could someone provide a simple example?  Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612910/how-to-set-cron-job-from-php-script from "Related" >>>

Comment: @Fred-ii- link totally works, but I always prefer using the API offered by cPanel https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/cPanel+API+2+Functions+-+Cron%3A%3Aadd_line